# Setting Canvas properties in an ItemsControl DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, itemscontrol

I'm trying to databind to this `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

By using this `DataTemplate`, I'm trying to individually position my `Node` elements on the `Canvas` correctly:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:EndNode}">
    <Controls:EndNodeControl Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=XPos}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=YPos}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

However, it's not working as expected. All my node elements are drawn on top of each other in the same position. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The attached properties only work on direct children of the `Canvas`. `ItemsControl` will place `ContentPresenter` controls as its direct children, so you might want to add a style for that as well:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found this solution myself about 5 minutes ago. I guess I was a bit quick on posting the question. :)

Comment: Hehe.. I love those AHA moment as well ;).. And its not all bad though.. Perhaps can your question help other people too one day..  You'll never know!

Comment: It helped here as well, +1 for all. :)

Comment: @skb I have the same problem, is there a Silverlight workaround for this?

Comment: What if my X and Y Position should be inside one of the objects of ItemsSource? I got a Point object in my ItemsSource.

Comment: I found a workaround for metro/UWP apps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37821355/3431319

Comment: @ElMac `<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=XPos}" />`

Comment: Even 14 yrs later. ;)