# WPF Binding Canvas Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

I'm working on a graph program that shows different datas in wpf. I want to bind Canvas Drawings to vertices.
I have nearly the same problem like in [Binding WPF Canvas Children to an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317713/binding-wpf-canvas-children-to-an-observablecollection) .

**(first question):** I want to Convert my Path Data *(see XAML)* into a Geometry. How?!

**(second question):** I want to Bind theese Paths to "Something" *(ItemsControl)* and show them.

I can show Canvas data by writing it directly into XAML:

```
              <Viewbox>

                    <Grid
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="8.0" ScaleY="8.0"></ScaleTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-50" Y="0"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                        <Path
                           Data="M 8.8733,6.4011 C 8.8733,5.3196 7.9235,4.4428 6.7518,4.4428 C 5.5802,4.4428 4.6304,5.3196 4.6304,6.4011 C 4.6304,7.4826 5.5802,8.3594 6.7518,8.3594 C 7.9235,8.3594 8.8733,7.4826 8.8733,6.4011 Z ">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Path
                          Data="M 8.8733,6.4011 C 8.8733,5.3196 7.9235,4.4428 6.7518,4.4428 C 5.5802,4.4428 4.6304,5.3196 4.6304,6.4011 C 4.6304,7.4826 5.5802,8.3594 6.7518,8.3594 C 7.9235,8.3594 8.8733,7.4826 8.8733,6.4011 Z "
                          Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="0.72" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                          StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round">
                        </Path>

                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>
```

But I want to change it according to vertex types.

```
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasVecPicture}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
```

My Vertex class:

```
        ...
        private ObservableCollection<Shape> canvasVecPicture;
        public ObservableCollection<Shape> CanvasVecPicture { get { return canvasVecPicture; } }
        ...


        Path myPath = new Path();
        myPath.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        myPath.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.MediumSlateBlue;
        myPath.StrokeThickness = 100;
        myPath.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        myPath.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();

        myEllipseGeometry.Center = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0);
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = 2000;
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = 2000;
        myPath.Data = myEllipseGeometry;

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Brushes.Blue.Color);
        ellipse.Fill = brush;
        ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
        ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

        ellipse.Width = 100;
        ellipse.Height = 100;




        canvasVecPicture = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
        canvasVecPicture.Add(myPath);
        canvasVecPicture.Add(ellipse);
```

In debugger the "get" method called lots of time, so I don't think it is a Binding Problem.

Comment: Where are you initializing the collection `canvasVecPicture`. I mean in constructor or where? Also check for binding errors in output window. Getter gets hit even in case you access it from code.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25031206/1136211) might be helpful.

Comment: canvasVecPicture = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
Last code snippet, and in ctor of the vertex class

Comment: I copy/paste your code in small sample and it does work. Most likely a binding failure. See in output window of Visual Studio. Do you see any binding errors over there?

Comment: I checked the output window, and no errors. Then I renamed the binding to check if it shows error, and the modified(wrong) version showed.

Comment: Can you post small sample working code replicating your problem?

Comment: Yes give me some minutes :).

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/GanvM/GraphSharpDemo.rar

In MainWindow.xaml, comment/uncomment static/binding parts

Comment: The problem was with the <Viewbox> </Viewbox> ... I removed it and solved my problem. One question left ^^... 

From
Data="M 8.8733,6.4011 C 8.8733,5.3196 ... Z " 
How Can I get Geometry object by using theese datas.

Comment: Refer to link post by Clemens. It will answer your query.

Comment: Ah there is a link actually, I see, I thougth he wrote it to your answer :)

Comment: Also this(How to convert from M 400,600 C 390,575 360,550 400,540 C 440,550 410,575 400,600 to Geometry)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1e4508c9-7ca5-47c0-a410-a05bf7c3a1f7/convert-geometry-pathdata-string-to-geometry?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question, but also I say thanks to Clemens & Rohit Vats.

**(first question)**: I want to Convert my Path Data (see XAML) into a Geometry. How?!

*Microsoft Soultion:*

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1e4508c9-7ca5-47c0-a410-a05bf7c3a1f7/convert-geometry-pathdata-string-to-geometry?forum=winappswithcsharp

*My Solution:*

```
var path = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
myPath.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.MediumSlateBlue;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 100;
myPath.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myPath.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

**path.Data = Geometry.Parse(M 400,600 C 390,...(DATAS);**
```

**(second question)**: I want to Bind theese Paths to "Something" (ItemsControl) and show them.
http://www.speedyshare.com/GanvM/GraphSharpDemo.rar

This is the "problematic" program, but you can get it from my question also. The solution was to remove the **< Viewbox > /< Viewbox > lines**