# How to bind a canvas' children to a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a canvas in one of my controls that I'd like to add/remove children to as a collection grows/shrinks.

I know that I can do this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Children>
        <Rectangle/>
        <TextBox/>
    </Canvas.Children>
</Canvas>
```

But these elements are statically defined. I envision something like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Children ItemsSource={Binding Path="ItemCollection", Converter="{StaticResource VisualConverter}}/>
</Canvas>
```

Is there something analogous to my above code, which actually works? I am aware of others posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317713/binding-wpf-canvas-children-to-an-observablecollection) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913792/wpf-canvas-how-to-add-children-dynamically-with-mvvm-code-behind) but a problem I see with these answers (for my purposes) is that you lose the capability of naming the canvas and accessing it in code behind: it's an element in a template, and is therefore out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to showing a collection of items (and support Binding), you should think about `ItemsControl`. In this case you can just set its `ItemsPanel` to some `ItemsPanelTemplate` holding a `Canvas`, something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection, 
                           Converter={StaticResource VisualConverter}}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now the `ItemsControl` acts like a `Canvas` holding some dynamic collection of children.

**Update**:

I doubt that you are following a wrong approach. Not sure how necessary those methods are so that you have to create a custom Canvas and require some easy access to it in codebehind. Using the standard Canvas would not be able to set some Binding for the `Children` property because it's readonly. Here I introduce a simple implementation for an attached property supporting binding instead of the standard non-attached Children property:

```
public static class CanvasService
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Children", typeof(IEnumerable<UIElement>), typeof(CanvasService), new UIPropertyMetadata(childrenChanged));
    private static Dictionary<INotifyCollectionChanged, Canvas> references = new Dictionary<INotifyCollectionChanged, Canvas>();
    public static IEnumerable<UIElement> GetChildren(Canvas cv)
    {
        return cv.GetValue(ChildrenProperty) as IEnumerable<UIElement>;
    }
    public static void SetChildren(Canvas cv, IEnumerable<UIElement> children)
    {
        cv.SetValue(ChildrenProperty, children);
    }
    private static void childrenChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = target as Canvas;
        repopulateChildren(canvas);
        var be = canvas.GetBindingExpression(ChildrenProperty);
        if (be != null)
        {
            var elements = (be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName == null ? be.ResolvedSource : be.ResolvedSource.GetType().GetProperty(be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName).GetValue(be.ResolvedSource)) as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (elements != null)
            {
                var cv = references.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == canvas);
                if (!cv.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<INotifyCollectionChanged,Canvas>)))
                     references.Remove(cv.Key);
                references[elements] = canvas;
                elements.CollectionChanged -= collectionChangedHandler;
                elements.CollectionChanged += collectionChangedHandler;
            }
        } else references.Clear();            
    }
    private static void collectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas cv;
        if (references.TryGetValue(sender as INotifyCollectionChanged, out cv))
        {                
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems) cv.Children.Add(item as UIElement);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems) cv.Children.Remove(item as UIElement);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    repopulateChildren(cv);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void repopulateChildren(Canvas cv)
    {
        cv.Children.Clear();
        var elements = GetChildren(cv);
        foreach (UIElement elem in elements){
            cv.Children.Add(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage in XAML**:

```
<Canvas local:CanvasService.Children="{Binding ItemCollection, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource VisualConverter}}"/>
```

Again I think you should consider for another approach. You should have some solution around the ItemsControl.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though as my question mentions, I face additional problems with this approach because the Canvas is now the child element for a template, and is therefore out of scope if I were to attempt to access it elsewhere in xaml or codebehind.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander ah I did not read the answers linked in your question. But this is the only way supporting binding. Why do you want to access the Canvas in codebehind?

Comment: @MichaelAlexander Note that we rarely have to do something directly with the instance of `Canvas`, we almost have to work with its children using some attached properties.

Comment: well my Canvas is actually a map that inherits from Canvas, and my intention is to use it to add elements which are bound to coordinates in a similar fashion to how canvas children are set by top and left. The map also has additional functionality, like centering on a set of coordinates, and I will need to call these methods in code behind.

Comment: Thanks King King, I will begin working on making my child type friendlier to the ItemsControl functionality.