# Binding to drawinggroup with unknown amount of geometrydrawings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, geometry

I am trying to make a pie chart custom control, and I will need to have an unknown number of pie slices. I am trying to accomplish this by creating a custom property, called maybe DrawingCode, and this code will be a string which can be converted and interpreted by a DrawingGroup. I was hoping for DrawingGroup.Children to be bound to TemplateBinding DrawingCode and use a converter, but I don't know how to convert a string into a list of GeometryDrawings. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the ResourceDictionary containing the generic for my PieChart control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PieChart}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PieChart}">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <DrawingImage>
                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup Children="{TemplateBinding DrawingCode}" />
                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        </DrawingImage>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your converter could return a Drawing (e.g. a DrawingGroup), which you would directly bind to the `DrawingImage.Drawing` property:

```
<DrawingImage Drawing="{Binding DrawingCode, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TemplatedParent}
    Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I make a DrawingGroup in the converter that has a list of children which contain GeometryDrawings in them?

Answer (score 0):

I would say - use a `ListBox` with a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel`. This way you get all the nice stuff from the ListBox - from multiple items to selection.

One approach to this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383858/how-to-use-canvas-as-the-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol-in-silverlight-3). Of course you still have to convert a `string` into a drawing, but this way you dont have to worry about having multiple items and of their positioning.