# How do I get a ContentPresenter's parent ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a drag behavior that I modified from answeres to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865441/move-items-in-a-canvas-using-mvvm). Almost everything works, except when I drag shapes past other shapes. Here is the XAML for my ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="audioDisplayItemsControl" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ct:Rectangle}">
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}"
                               Height="{Binding Height}"
                               Fill="Black"
                               IsManipulationEnabled="True"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ct:Line}">
                    <!-- Points reletive to ItemContainer -->
                    <Line X1="0"
                          Y1="0"
                          X2="0"
                          Y2="{Binding Length}"
                          Stroke="Gray"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          StrokeDashArray="4 1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ct:LabeledLine}">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- Points reletive to ContentPresenter-->
                        <Line X1="0"
                              Y1="0"
                              X2="0"
                              Y2="{Binding Length}"
                              Stroke="Red"
                              StrokeThickness="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="4,1,0,0" Foreground="White">
                            <Run Text="("/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Num}"/>
                            <Run Text=") "/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    
                    <Canvas>
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.30"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.33"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.67"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.7"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                    </Canvas>
                    
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ct:DragBehavior.Drag" Value="{Binding CanDrag}"/>  <----- DragBehavior attached here
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Here is what my `ItemsControl` looks like before I add my list of shapes to it
[image: Blank Items Control]

After I add the shapes it looks like this
[image]

Only the red lines (`ct:LabeledLine`) are draggable, and only along the x-axis. My problem is when I drag a red line past the one to its right as shown

[image]

The red line for "(0) New 0" is past the red line for "(1) New 1" but **not** past the text for "(1) New 1". Since (0) was added before (1), the `ContentPresenter` for (0) is behind the `ContentPresenter` for (1). Now I can no longer drag (0), unless I move (1) out of the way. This is because the drag behavior is attached to the `contentPresenter`, not the red line.

From the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event, I can get the `ContentPresenter` (it's just the sender), but I need to get the parent `ItemsControl` so I can get a list of its children, sort them by their x position values and assign `ZIndex` based on their sort order. This I think should solve my problem.

I just don't know how to get the parent `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could walk up the visual tree manually using [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent).

This is a method I use when I need to do things like this:

```vb
Public Function FindVisualParent(Of ParentType As DependencyObject)(obj As DependencyObject) As ParentType
    Dim Parent As DependencyObject = obj

    Do Until Parent Is Nothing OrElse TypeOf Parent Is ParentType
        If TypeOf Parent IsNot Visual AndAlso TypeOf Parent IsNot Media3D.Visual3D AndAlso TypeOf Parent Is FrameworkContentElement Then
            Parent = DirectCast(Parent, FrameworkContentElement).Parent
        Else
            Parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Parent)
        End If
    Loop

    Return Parent
End Function
```

I took the time to convert the above to C#:

```
public ParentType FindVisualParent<ParentType>(DependencyObject obj) where ParentType : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject Parent = obj;

    while (Parent != null && !(Parent is ParentType))
    {
        if (Parent is FrameworkContentElement contentElement)
            Parent = contentElement.Parent;
        else
            Parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Parent);
    }

    return (ParentType)Parent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra effort of putting into c# for me.