# Binding a collection to SelectedItems in a ListBox without violating MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ObservableCollection called **SelectedVNodes**' and it contains items from the ObservableCollection **VNodes**.

The **SelectedVNodes** should only contain nodes whose property `IsSelected = True`, otherwise if 'false' it shouldn't be in the list.

```
ObservableCollection<VNode> SelectedVNodes {...}
ObservableCollection<VNode> VNodes {...}
```

I've bound my property to maintain being updated on selection change by using this setter

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

However that is about as far as I got. I do not know how to append/remove this item from the SelectedVNodes list based on this property changing.

Here is the VNode class

```
public class VNode : NotifyBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Kids { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref isSelected, value);
            Console.WriteLine("selected/deselected");
        }
    }
}
```

NotifyBase derives from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Hi, you should add a command and a commandParameter inside ur checkbox declaration. Add Command inside ur viewmodel, the command parameter should be the checked element (VNode Type), update the property IsSelected = false and it should update normaly. Take note that you will have to RelativeSource the command since it's nested in the listview

Comment: @Guillaume could you show exactly how i would do this?

Comment: http://wpftution.blogspot.ca/2012/05/mvvm-sample-using-datagrid-control-in.html Its the same implementation instead of button its Checkbox, in removeCommand you would update ur Vnodes.IsSelected = true and you should change AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" "DataGrid"  To Gridview or listView . Sorry for the quick reply I'm during lunchtime :)

Comment: What control are you using to display/select the `VNode`s? If the control supports multi-select then it already should have a collection like `SelectedItems` or something similar.

Comment: I'm selecting things on a canvas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, at the conclusion of our last episode, we were using some whimsical WPF control that doesn't let you bind `SelectedItems` properly, so that's out. But if you can do it, it's by far the best way:

```
<NonWhimsicalListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding VNodes}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedVNodes}"
    />
```

But if you're using `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox`, you have to write it yourself using an attached property, which is actually not so bad. There's a lot of code here, but it's almost entirely boilerplate (most of the C# code in this attached property was created by a VS IDE code snippet). Nice thing here is it's general and any random passerby can use it on any `ListBox` that's got anything in it.

```
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    #region AttachedProperties.SelectedItems Attached Property
    public static IList GetSelectedItems(ListBox obj)
    {
        return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItems(ListBox obj, IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty 
        SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SelectedItems", 
                typeof(IList), 
                typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, 
                    SelectedItems_PropertyChanged));

    private static void SelectedItems_PropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lb = d as ListBox;
        IList coll = e.NewValue as IList;

        //  If you want to go both ways and have changes to 
        //  this collection reflected back into the listbox...
        if (coll is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            (coll as INotifyCollectionChanged)
                .CollectionChanged += (s, e3) =>
            {
                //  Haven't tested this branch -- good luck!
                if (null != e3.OldItems)
                    foreach (var item in e3.OldItems)
                        lb.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                if (null != e3.NewItems)
                    foreach (var item in e3.NewItems)
                        lb.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            };
        }

        if (null != coll)
        {
            if (coll.Count > 0)
            {
                //  Minor problem here: This doesn't work for initializing a 
                //  selection on control creation. 
                //  When I get here, it's because I've initialized the selected 
                //  items collection that I'm binding. But at that point, lb.Items 
                //  isn't populated yet, so adding these items to lb.SelectedItems 
                //  always fails. 
                //  Haven't tested this otherwise -- good luck!
                lb.SelectedItems.Clear();
                foreach (var item in coll)
                    lb.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            lb.SelectionChanged += (s, e2) =>
            {
                if (null != e2.RemovedItems)
                    foreach (var item in e2.RemovedItems)
                        coll.Remove(item);
                if (null != e2.AddedItems)
                    foreach (var item in e2.AddedItems)
                        coll.Add(item);
            };
        }
    }
    #endregion AttachedProperties.SelectedItems Attached Property
}
```

Assuming `AttachedProperties` is defined in whatever the "`local:`" namespace is in your XAML...

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding VNodes}" 
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    local:AttachedProperties.SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedVNodes}"
    />
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Node> _selectedVNodes 
    = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
public ObservableCollection<Node> SelectedVNodes
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedVNodes;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to go there, I can think of <s>three</s>three and a half straightforward ways of doing this offhand:

1. When the parent viewmodel creates a `VNode`, it adds a handler to the new `VNode`'s `PropertyChanged` event. In the handler, it adds/removes `sender` from `SelectedVNodes` according to (bool)e.NewValue

   ```
   var newvnode = new VNode();
   newvnode.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => {
       if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected") {
           if ((bool)e.NewValue) {
               //  If not in SelectedVNodes, add it.
           } else {
               //  If in SelectedVNodes, remove it.
           }
       }
   };

   //  blah blah blah
   ```
2. Do that event, but instead of adding/removing, just recreate `SelectedVNodes`:

   ```
   var newvnode = new VNode();
   newvnode.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => {
       if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected") {
           //  Make sure OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVNodes") is happening!
           SelectedVNodes = new ObservableCollection<VNode>(
                   VNodes.Where(vn => vn.IsSelected)
               );
       }
   };
   ```
3. Do that event, but don't make `SelectedVNodes` Observable at all:

   ```
   var newvnode = new VNode();
   newvnode.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => {
       if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected") {
           OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVNodes");
       }
   };

   //  blah blah blah much else blah blah

   public IEnumerable<VNode> SelectedVNodes {
       get { return VNodes.Where(vn => vn.IsSelected); }
   }
   ```
4. Give `VNode` a Parent property. When the parent viewmodel creates a `VNode`, it gives each `VNode` a Parent reference to the owner of `SelectedVNodes` (presumably itself). In `VNode.IsSelected.set`, the VNode does the add or remove on `Parent.SelectedVNodes`.

   ```
   //  In class VNode
   private bool _isSelected = false;
   public bool IsSelected {
       get { return _isSelected; }
       set {
           _isSelected = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
           // Elided: much boilerplate checking for redundancy, null parent, etc.
           if (IsSelected)
               Parent.SelectedVNodes.Add(this);
           else
               Parent.SelectedVNodes.Remove(this);
        }
    }
   ```

None of the above is a work of art. Version 1 is least bad maybe.

Don't use the `IEnumerable` one if you've got a very large number of items. On the other hand, it relieves you of the responsibility to make this two-way, i.e. if some consumer messes with `SelectedVNodes` directly, you should really be handling its `CollectionChanged` event and updating the `VNodes` in question. Of course then you have to make sure you don't accidentally recurse: Don't add one to the collection that's already there, and don't set `vn.IsSelected = true` if `vn.IsSelected` is true already. If your eyes are glazing over like mine right now and you're starting to feel the walls closing in, allow me to recommend option #3.

Maybe `SelectedVNodes` should *publicly* expose `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<VNode>`, to get you off that hook. In that case number 1 is your best bet, because the `VNodes` won't have access to the VM's private mutable `ObservableCollection<VNode>`.

But take your pick.

Comment: Those all great approaches to this. In my case the control does not have a selected Items property since I'm using a canvas. Is there a way to add an extensions to the canvas to collect the selected items?

Comment: So Canvas is the ItemsPanel used by an ItemsControl (or whatever)? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1265419/424129 or something?

Comment: does that help make things easier at all?

Comment: @JokerMartini OK, I wrote an attachment property that reflects a ListBox's SelectedItems state to a collection (anything that implements `IList` provided by a viewmodel. Makes no difference what the ItemsPanel is.

Comment: @JokerMartini Well, that's done. It works for reflecting changes in selection coming in through the UI. Haven't tested changes going the other way.

Comment: How do i use this with a canvas?

Comment: I thought you said you were using the Canvas as the ItemsPanel for a collection control. If the collection control supports selection, it's very likely a ListBox or a ListView (which is a subclass of ListBox). If you want to select items in a Canvas, use a ListBox with a Canvas for the ItemsPanel; virtually all forms of suicide are preferable to reimplementing selection by hand. And I'm specifically thinking about a large number of small sharks here.

Comment: Alright sounds great! You are correct, I'm using the listbox. Thanks for your help. I'm going to test this out right now. I'm definitely not recreating the wheel of selection!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100507/discussion-between-jokermartini-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this without the use of INotifyPropertyChanged, would be to add an `if` construct to the `setter`:

```
private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref isSelected, value);

            if(isSelected)
            {
                if(!SelectedVNodes.Any(v => v.Name == this.Name))
                SelectedVNodes.Add(this);
            }
            else{
                if(SelectedVNodes.Any(v => v.Name == this.Name))
                SelectedVNodes.Remove(this);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("selected/deselected");
        }
    }
```