# Pattern for delegating events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, design-patterns, mvvm

I use MVVM for a desktop application. I have a model called `Calculator`, which does very expensive calculations in a own thread. The `MainViewModel` references the `Calculator` and uses the calculated results. The view takes the results and displays them.

> The problem is, that the `Calculator` returns the calculation results by using an event. And I don't want to bind the view to the event from the `Calculator` because the used `Calculator` can change on runtime. As solution I have used the same event twice, which I don't like, has someone a better approach.

**Model:**

```
public class Calculator
{
    public event CalculatedHandler Calculated;
    public delegate void CalculatedHandler(object sender, IEnumerable<string> values);

    protected void OnCalculated(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        Calculated?.Invoke(this, values);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Calculate);
    }

    private void Calculate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            // Do expensive stuff
            values.Add(i + "");
            OnCalculated(values);
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CalculatorViewModel
{
    private Calculator calculator;

    public event CalculatedHandler Calculated;
    public delegate void CalculatedHandler(object sender, IEnumerable<string> values);

    protected void OnCalculated(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        Calculated?.Invoke(this, values);
    }

    public CalculatorViewModel()
    {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.Calculated += Calculator_Calculated;
    }

    private void Calculator_Calculated(object sender, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        OnCalculated(values);
    }
}
```

**View XAML:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:CalculatorViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**View code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContextChanged += MainWindow_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void MainWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CalculatorViewModel viewModel = e.NewValue as CalculatorViewModel;

        viewModel.Calculated += ViewModel_Calculated;
    }

    private void ViewModel_Calculated(object sender, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        // Draw values on the canvas
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) in your model and view model.

Comment: @Clemens can you give me an example on the code above

Comment: Sorry, you could easily do that yourself after reading the artice I've linked.

Comment: Without the INPC interface on your VM you're not really doing MVVM.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry the code above is only a small example - the original code does contain INPC

Comment: Then you simplified too much - as the answer below shows, INPC is crucial to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the view model, which is a common way to update view when data changes. It will work fine with bindings (I think it is possible to use `ItemsControl` with `Canvas` as its panel to display calculation results without code-behind).

```
public class CalculatorViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Calculator calculator;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public IEnumerable<string> CalcValues { get; set; }

    public CalculatorViewModel()
    {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.Calculated += Calculator_Calculated;
    }

    private void Calculator_Calculated(object sender, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        CalcValues = values;
        PropertyChanged?.(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CalcValues"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but than I have to bind to the `CalcValues` in the code behind from the view, so that it is posible to draw the values, etc. - is this what you meant?

Comment: @KevinWallis, I had in mind smth like `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CalcValues}">` in xaml, not in code-behind; and ItemsControl + Canvas combo is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265364/setting-canvas-properties-in-an-itemscontrol-datatemplate. You can also continue with code behind approach, but instead of `Calculated ` event subscribe to `PropertyChanged`

Comment: Thx for the hints!