# MVVM Canvas with multiple duplicate children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this panel that I created in a Winforms application, and I'm trying to duplicate it in a WPF mvvm application.

[image]

I'm still relatively new to mvvm and I don't know the best way to do this. Each of the 10 small rectangles can hold identical data, so I assume that this will be a Model:

**ButtonDataModel**

```
public class ButtonDataModel
{
    public SolidColorBrush BackGroundColor { get; set; }
    public int BorderThickness { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BorderColor { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush TextColor { get; set; }
}
```

Then, there will be a User Control that displays the data:
**ButtonDataUserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Views.ButtonDataPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModel"
             d.DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:ButtonDataViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="80">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{Binding ButtonData.BackGroundColor}" BorderThickness="{Binding ButtonData.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{Binding ButtonData.BorderColor}">
            <Label Content="{Binding ButtonData.Text}" Foreground="{Binding ButtonData.TextColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then I have another User Control with holds all of the different smaller user controls:
**LcdScreen.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DekSim.Views.LcdScreen"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DekSim.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="90" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonDisplays}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ButtonDataUserControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The ViewModel for each of the rectangles:
**ButtonDataViewModel**

```
public class FabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ButtonDataModel _buttonData;

    #region Properties
    public ButtonDataModel ButtonData
    { get { return _buttonData; } set { SetProperty(ref _buttonData, value); } }
    public int ButtonNumber { get; set; }
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

The main window xaml that contains the single LcdScreen control:
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel}"
        Title="Test Application" Height="750" Width="1300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        MinHeight="600" MinWidth="800"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Grid>
    ....
        <views:LcdScreen Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    ....
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And finally, the MainWindowViewModel that contains the reference to the ButtonDataModels:
**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<ButtonDataViewModel> _buttonDisplays;

    public ObservableCollection<ButtonDataViewModel> ButtonDisplays
    {
        get { return _buttonDisplays; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _buttonDisplays, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        ButtonDisplays = new ObservableCollection<ButtonDataViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ButtonDisplays.Add(new ButtonViewModel() 
                { 
                    ButtonNumber = i + 1,
                    XPos = x,
                    YPos = y,
                    ButtonData = new ButtonDataModel() 
                    {
                        Text = $"Btn{i + 1}" 
                    }
                 });
            x +=80;
            if (i == 5)
            {
                x = 0;
                y += 50;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this set up correctly?**
**How do I bind the Model data to the Views?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for the `BackGroundColor` and `TextColor` properties should be `Brush` instead of `Color`.

If I understand your setup correctly, you should also use an `ItemTemplate` to display the `ButtonDataPanel` for each `ButtonDataModel` in `ButtonDisplays`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonDisplays}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ButtonDataPanel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't throw any errors, but how do I get each of the 10 ButtonDataPanels placed on the Canvas in the correct location?

Comment: You bind the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties of the `ItemContainer` to source properties of your data object as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265364/setting-canvas-properties-in-an-itemscontrol-datatemplate).